# Xamarin Studio 5 Unity Add-in Repository

Tags: debugging, unity-game-engine, xamarin, add-in

I was trying to get Xamarin Studio 5 setup on OS X since it's a much better IDE than the one Unity ships with and I successfully got it working as an editor with Unity. However, I have read that it is possible to get the debugger working with it.

Apparently in Xamarin Studio 4, there was an add-in in the alpha channel (from here http://www.cliffordroche.ca/monodevelop-4-xamarin-studio-debugging-in-unity/ and other sources) and there was a Unity section in the Gallery tab of the add-in manager that included a Unity Utilities add-in.

In Xamarin Studio 5, I don't see this. Does anyone know if it's possible to get Unity debugging support working in Xamarin Studio 5 even if you have to add a manual add-in repository? I can't seem to find any information on this.

Comment: I also look for the add-in, have you found it? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the beta channel http://www.cliffordroche.ca/unity-debugger-for-monodevelop-5-xamarin-2-updated/

Currently it doesn't support unity 4.5 debugger features like ios usb debugging and is some what unstable sometimes with unity 4.5. But is stable for versions till unity 4.3.x

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach the process while the Unity player is not running.  You also have to stop the debugger in Xamarin studio before you stop the player in Unity3D, otherwise Unity will crash.

It's not ideal, but it works.