# How does monodevelop summary autocompletion work

Tags: autocomplete, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

In monodevelop, if I declare a variable like so...

```
public int foo = 1;
```

Then in the line directly above it, i type `///`, it will automatically generate this....

```
/// <summary>
/// The foo.
/// </summary>
```

How is this happening? Which files in unity are causing this behaviour? I want to know because I want to  modify it to add some other generated code.

Comment: it's a monodevelop feature, something like "autodoc", you should find more about that in monodev help or website docs

Answer (score 0):

> How is this happening? Which files in unity are causing this behaviour? I want to know because I want to modify it to add some other generated code.

You won't be able to modify Unity's MonoDevelop that easily. They are actually stuck in some old version (which presumably will make your life even more complicated if you want to change its behaviour) that is years old.

Some people use nowadays Xamarin Studio (instead of Unity's MonoDevelop) or the last version of MonoDevelop, with a [Unity plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24311618/xamarin-studio-5-unity-add-in-repository). This would be a more reliable way for you to go ahead and change MonoDevelop's documentation-autocompletion behaviour, by looking at its [upstream source code](http://github.com/mono/monodevelop), and maybe creating an AddIn yourself for the desired functionality.

Comment: i downloaded the open source monodevelop code on github and i found the exact file that is creating the auto doc. Unfortunately... I could not compile it, i was getting import errors that i dont know how to fix.

Comment: you have to compile it in the command line, did you follow the instructions in the README? if you still have problems after doing these, post a new stackoverflow question about the compilation problem you get